# I can no longer play my songs consecutively on my iphone

Tags: iphone

I have been playing music on my iPhone for years, updating it with new songs I purchase regularly from iTunes.
Recently, my list of songs looks different and I can only play one song at a time, and if I don't stop to change songs, the song just repeats over and over, even when I hit shuffle. Very frustrating while I'm trying to run with continuous music.
I've noticed the red icon has recently turned white.  Not sure if this is relevant. 
How do I get back to my original format?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Apple has updated the music app. The icon changed with the update in iOS 7, I believe, and the music app saw some big changes with iOS 8.4. Some of the UI is harder for me to figure out and use but all of the old functionality should still be there.

To play an entire playlist, tap the Play icon in the upper right of the playlist. It should be overlaid onto album artwork (likely of 4 albums).

To have continuous repeat, after starting the playlist, tap the bar just above the navigation bar to see "Now Playing". Then, at the bottom (you may need to scroll down) there are standard icons for repeat and shuffle. If the repeat icon in the lower right had a "1" next to it, it is set to Repeat 1. Tap the icon to change it.

You can find more information about the new Music app here:
http://m.imore.com/how-use-new-music-app-iphone-and-ipad-ultimate-guide

Answer (score 0):

Mine started this on the recent update. Turns out I had accidentally hit the replay arrows at the bottom. When I finally put my glasses on I could see the little one inside the arrows. Clicked on it and it's fixed.